# How to use to_char in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I need to change the date format. And for this I want to use `to_char`. But when I do this:

```
Sequelize.where(
    Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col('to_char("users.date_work", \'DD.MM.YYYY\')'), 'varchar'),
    {
        [Op.like]: `%${req.query.search}%`
    }
)
```

This error occurs:

> table \ "to_char (users.date_work, 'DD.MM \" is not in the FROM clause

How to use `to_char` in sequelize correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Sequelize.literal()` rather than .col()... and you need not cast the result:

```
where : 
    Sequelize.where(
       Sequelize.literal('to_char("users.date_work", \'DD.MM.YYYY\')'),
          { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.search}%` }
       )
```

FWIW, using LIKE on a date field may be fragile.  Generally it is better to use BETWEEN two dates.